# how to set condition color button imageAsset by catching index in Gesturdetector flutter?

Tags: arrays, list, if-statement, colors, gesturedetector

I want to hide previous button on first page and show next button to scroll to page2, but previous and next button showing on page2 and next button hide when into end page in Gesturedetector by catching index and this button I use ImageAsset instead icon.

I tried to set condition but it didn't work.